# Using st.countTokens() in my Java code doesn't work as intended

Tags: java, string, loops, variables

I am coding in Java and trying to use a while loop to add all of the values of a string to an array that were set up as tokens separated by commas. At some point, the values just turn into 0, and I don't know why.

My array is a double array called "prices". My string is named "values". The loop I am using is this:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(values,",");
prices = new double[st.countTokens()];
for (int i = 0; i < st.countTokens(); i++) {
     token = st.nextToken();
     double price = Double.parseDouble(token);
     prices[i] = price;
}
```

When I use 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 as the inputs, the output that I expect is to have prices[0] through prices[8] be equal to the 9 values that I input for the tokens, but this is the output I get:

```
Please enter the price values using numbers and decimals only!
Input 0 at any time to stop entering values!
Enter the price value: 1
Enter the price value: 2
Enter the price value: 3
Enter the price value: 4
Enter the price value: 5
Enter the price value: 6
Enter the price value: 7
Enter the price value: 8
Enter the price value: 9
Enter the price value: 0

Show prices array:
prices[0] = 1.0
prices[1] = 2.0
prices[2] = 3.0
prices[3] = 4.0
prices[4] = 5.0
prices[5] = 0.0
prices[6] = 0.0
prices[7] = 0.0
prices[8] = 0.0
```

Here is my entire code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class ArrayInputShow {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        int count = 0, numTokens = 0;
        double prices[], temp;
        String values = "", tempInput = "", token = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the price values using numbers and decimals only!");
        System.out.println("Input 0 at any time to stop entering values!");
        while (true) {
            if (count != 0) {
                values = values + ",";
            }
            System.out.print("Enter the price value: ");
            tempInput = input.nextLine();
            if (tempInput.equals("0")) {
                break;
            }
            values = values + tempInput;
            count++;
        }
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(values,",");
        numTokens = st.countTokens();
        prices = new double[st.countTokens()];
        for (int i = 0; i < st.countTokens(); i++) {
            token = st.nextToken();
            double price = Double.parseDouble(token);
            prices[i] = price;
        }

        System.out.println(""); //break
        System.out.println("Show prices array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("prices[" + i + "] = " + prices[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(""); //break
        System.out.println("Show prices array backwards:");
        for (int i = prices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("prices[" + i + "] = " + prices[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(""); //break
        System.out.println("Show prices array sorted from least expensive to most expensive:");
        for (int j = 0; j < prices.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (prices.length - (1 + j)); i++) {
                if (prices[i] > prices [i + 1]) {
                    temp = prices[i + 1];
                    prices[i + 1] = prices[i];
                    prices[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("prices[" + i + "] = " + prices[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This was my first attempt at making an array that declares and initializes depending on the users input and how many inputs the user gives.

I ended up finding a solution to this problem by declaring a variable  "numTokens' and using that in place of using st.countTokens itself in the loop. However, I am still confused as to why it didn't work with st.countTokens. Isn't it the same thing?

This is what worked for me:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(values,",");
numTokens = st.countTokens();
prices = new double[numTokens];
for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; i++) {
     token = st.nextToken();
     double price = Double.parseDouble(token);
     prices[i] = price;
}
```

But, like I said, I don't understand why this works, or how to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: StringTokenizer might not be what you want to use. Just use the split method of the String class instead, and the size of the resulting array 'll give you your number of tokens

Comment: I know you're just testing around with Java but I would recommand using `List` as the number of items is not determined before. If you just wanna use arrays just ask the user for the total number of inputs first. This way you don't have to store inputs in a String variable

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is supersed by `String.split` really. But you don't need it. It's pointless to concatenate input only to split it again. Just read the input and store it. You can use `List<Double>`

Comment: If you're determined to use an array rather than a `List` then over-allocate and only use the array up to the value zero

Comment: I removed your request on how to optimize this code, as that made your question unfocused, and thus off-topic.

Comment: Stultuske galalem g00se thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in these two lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < st.countTokens(); i++) {
    token = st.nextToken();
```

With the `st.nextToken();` you basically pop a value from the StringTokenizer, so the `st.countTokens()` will decrease every iteration. If you add a debug printline `System.out.println(st.countTokens());` between the two lines above, you'll see it'll print `9,8,7,6,5`, at which point `i<5` will stop the loop.

The most straight-forward fix is to put the `st.countTokens();` in a variable before the loop:

```
int countTokens = st.countTokens();
for (int i = 0; i < countTokens ; i++) {
    token = st.nextToken();
```

Although usually you'd simply use a `while(st.hasMoreElements())` instead like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    token = st.nextToken();
    double price = Double.parseDouble(token);
    prices[i] = price;
    i++;
}
```

---

As for a general tip: I assume you're first reading all your prices and only then convert it to a double-array, because you don't know beforehand how many prices the user will input and how large the array will be. In that case, there is the `ArrayList`. :)

The advantage with the ArrayList is also that you can use builtins for the reversing and sorting, so you won't have to do so manually, like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class ArrayInputShow {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ArrayInputShow program = new ArrayInputShow();

        List<Double> prices = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the price values using numbers and decimals only!");
        System.out.println("Input 0 at any time to stop entering values!");
        while (true) {
            //System.out.print("Enter the price value: ");
            double price = input.nextDouble();
            if (price == 0) {
              break;
            }
            prices.add(price);
        }

        program.printLinebreakAndMessage("Show given prices:");
        program.printPrices(prices);

        program.printLinebreakAndMessage("Show prices backwards:");
        Collections.reverse(prices);
        program.printPrices(prices);

        program.printLinebreakAndMessage("Show prices sorted from least expensive to most expensive:");
        Collections.sort(prices);
        program.printPrices(prices);
    }

    private void printLinebreakAndMessage(String msg) {
        System.out.println(); //break
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    private void printPrices(List<Double> prices) {
      for (double price : prices) {
          System.out.println(price);
      }
    }
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##tVTLjtMwFN37Ky5dpQsy5TVAS5FGwAJpkEbqErFw49vUrR@R7aRToX57sROP6mTaGVjgTZT7OOf4@tgb2tCXG7Y9HrmstHGw8YG8dlzki4IqhWZGHmVuuXVnwjfG0P2F3BctBBaOa2VnhBSCWgtt/XdV1W6x1jv4TcCvql4KXoB11PlPozkDSbmCbOEMVyVQU9qfv8axOqwBTGV0aaiEOSjcDZLZ2JM/9AWln75qz4effRcv0KZNaTr0PbTFsQAPoLEhxrLF3jqUOVcpTwzq2uWeRTmhstGdQGoRUDmP5NbY8UNDRe1V1DbsVNVyicYCVQwYFlxSYUErsX8xSuWcQW/3CxOgzjfvwXGJ4LSfqa46ygDfcfWwdmsuEDJnakwHHNbV1ZAoG307p34KKWJYrJ1hrJl3c8sV3rtuuNmgnK8gi7VzmAx1ACwN0m2/5dD7644yp4x1OAn@4XQq0SbdXm65whb3RrEfaC0tMRu1bip5gypCTtOd9frv2nxHZ9Oz/0uW6L4lLbY7alifKbk6ucHGWwJPTP9TjvVXGBmsjJYQ/OoA7ytU1o8k2EnqNHJRckD5R73JUflYQx12D8FF2fFtkLZM/XLmaoxn3slt91NVAecZFVHymTfkpGClDWQ9908f1VxQ0DfuIWo5HI8fyBvyjrwn1@Q1eUU@krdk8gc) (Although all inputs have to be given at once, so I've removed the `System.out.print("Enter the price value: ");` here.)

Comment: thank you this was very helpful and informative